# Where did 0 index go in return statements of tuples in this sorting algorithm?

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I'm looking at a sorting algorithm to put lowercase letters in front, then uppercase, then odd, and lastly even. For example `String1234` becomes `ginrtS1324`

**Code**

```
def getKey(x):
    if x.islower():
        return(1,x)
    elif x.isupper():
        return(2,x)
    elif x.isdigit():
        if int(x)%2 == 1:
            return(3,x)
        else:
            return(4,x)

print(*sorted('String1234',key=getKey),sep='')
```

I understand that tuples are returned as `(1, g), (1,i)... (2, S), (3, 1), (3, 3) (4, 2), (4,4)`. What I don't understand is why a list is created: `['g', 'i', 'n', 'r', 't', '1', '3', '2', '4']` and what happened to the 0 indexes of the tuples?

Comment: Is `ginrtS1324` your output?

Comment: Your question says that you want to sort characters in this manner
->  lowercase letters in front, then uppercase, then odd, and lastly even.
However , the output you are looking for , i.e. , tringS1324 is not sorted. The correct output should be ginrtS1324 . Please check your question.

Comment: @NavanK. Yea, sorry, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sorted` returns a sorted list with the elements of whatever iterable you pass into it:

```
>>> sorted('String1234')
['1', '2', '3', '4', 'S', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'r', 't']
```

If you want to turn this back into a string, an easy way is `join()`:

```
>>> ''.join(sorted('String1234'))
'1234Sginrt'
```

If you pass a `key` parameter, the resulting keys (obtained by calling the `key` function on each element to be sorted) are used for the comparison within the sort, but the output is still built out of the original elements, not the keys!

```
>>> ''.join(sorted('String1234', key=getKey))
'ginrtS1324'
```

If you wanted to get the list of tuples rather than a list of letters, you'd do that by mapping your key function over the list itself before sorting it (and do that instead of passing it as a separate parameter to `sorted`):

```
>>> sorted(map(getKey, 'String1234'))
[(1, 'g'), (1, 'i'), (1, 'n'), (1, 'r'), (1, 't'), (2, 'S'), (3, '1'), (3, '3'), (4, '2'), (4, '4')]
>>> ''.join(map(lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x)), sorted(map(getKey, 'String1234'))))
'1g1i1n1r1t2S31334244'
```

Comment: Ah, so to reiterate 'String1234' are the original elements that are sorted? The return statements of the tuples are not the things that get sorted. Where do they actually go? Are they just pointers?

Comment: They're only used within the implementation of `sorted` and are not returned as part of its output, which means they get garbage-collected after the function returns.